# How to translate Go des code in javascript

Tags: javascript, go, des

***I want to translate Go DES code in javascript***

This is my Go code, use des zeropadding to encrypt. Now I want use javascript to get the same function, but I try it many times, the result is always wrong.

```golang
package zeropadding

import (
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/des"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    text := DesEncrypt([]byte("12345678"), []byte("12345678"))
    fmt.Println(strings.ToUpper(hex.EncodeToString(text)))
}

func DesEncrypt(origData, key []byte) []byte {
    iv := []byte{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    block, err := des.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    origData = ZeroPadding(origData)
    blockMode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
    crypted := make([]byte, len(origData))
    blockMode.CryptBlocks(crypted, origData)
    return crypted
}

func ZeroPadding(in []byte) []byte {
    length := len(in)

    blockCount := length / 8
    out := make([]byte, (blockCount+1)*8)
    var i int
    for i = 0; i < length; i++ {
        out[i] = in[i]
    }
    return out
}
```

how to use javascript to do it

```js
const CryptoJS = require('./crypto-js.min')

function encryptByDES(message, key, iv) {
    var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    var ivHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);
    encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(message, keyHex, {
            iv: ivHex,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
        }
    );
    return encrypted.ciphertext.toString();
}

console.log(encryptByDES("12345678", "12345678", 0))
```

I use the lib `crypto-js`, use mode `CryptoJS.mode.CBC` and padding `CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding`, but the result is not equals with the Go code output.

Comment: The CryptoJS code does not append a full block (8 bytes for DES) of 0x00 values if the length of the plaintext is already an integer multiple of the block size, the Golang code does. Also, in the CryptoJS code for a zero vector, do not pass 0 as the IV, but `"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"`. Please note, both codes are insecure: DES is insecure and has been for about 20 years. The use of a static IV is also insecure. And Zero padding is unreliable. Better apply AES, a randomly generated IV for each encryption and PKCS7 padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are issues with both your go code and your javascript which is probably confusing things. (caveat - I'm far from being an encryption expert!).

## Go

Zero pad should be filling the []byte out to a multiple of the blocksize (8 in your case) but as it stands if the input is 8 bytes long you will pad out to 16 bytes. Try:

`blockCount := (length - 1) / blockSize`

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IsvH1mDgMpX)

## Javascript

You are providing the IV as a number but then converting it as if it was utf8. Lets mirror what you are doing in go:

```
var ivHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);
```

And pass the IV in as hex:

```
console.log(encryptByDES("1234567890", "12345678", "0000000000000000"))
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0x13s5w/)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use [WebAssembly](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WebAssembly) (see [webassembly.org](https://webassembly.org/)), considering that:

- you can compile your Go project to wasm

  ```
    GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm
  ```

(see "[Best Practices for WebAssembly using GoLang (1.15+)](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/best-practices-for-webassembly-using-golang-1-15-8dfa439827b8)" from [Cesar William Alvarenga](https://twitter.com/cesarwbr) for more best practices)

- you can [call said wasm from your Javascript project](https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-02-06-golang-wasm-3-interacting-with-js-from-go/#calling-go-from-javascript)

Comment: I have try wasm before, it run ok on chrome, but I need use it in WeChat miniprogram, wasm not supported

Comment: @ihsusta OK. Then I don't know. I didn't see WeChat in your question.